# 2nd Steam Account on the same Computer?

Tags: steam, team-fortress-2

Will Creating a second steam account work on the same computer?

Will I be able to play TF2 with the already downloaded version as an F2P on the new account, or will I have to download a 2nd version of TF2 for the same computer?

If so, I know my items would not be affected because of the cloud, but would this be considered cheating towards VAC.

If I need to download TF2 again on the same computer as the F2P version, how will I tell the difference between that and the version I payed for years ago? I do plan on buying a premium for the 2nd account, and I don't need the 2 accounts to run at the same time. One at a time is fine.

Answer (score 3):

> Will Creating a 2nd steam account work on the same computer / will i be able to play tf2 with the already downloaded version as an f2p on the new account, or will i have to download a 2nd verion of tf2 for the same computer?

The currently downloaded version of TF2 will do. You do not ostensibly need to download a different version for different accounts.

> If so, i know my items would not be affected because of the cloud but would this be considered cheating towards VAC

No. Items are bound to accounts. Different accounts have different inventories and trading them between accounts involves being logged in with both Steam accounts at the same time.

> would this be considered cheating towards VAC

We can't tell you. Steam probably has ways to know what you're up to, but so far has ostensibly done nothing about it.

> how will i tell the difference between that and the Version i payed for years ago?

One has the [Proof of Purchase](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Proof_of_purchase), the other won't.

Answer (score 1):

You can have as many accounts as you want on the same computer, they will all use the same version of Team Fortress that you downloaded for your original account.

Team Fortress 2 will treat your accounts differently in-game if one is 'premium' and the other is F2P. There will be no difference if you go premium from F2P.

Valve will not ban you for having multiple accounts on the same machine. However, as linked to below, the FAQ mentions Valve is monitoring account creation for abuse.

Here is a link to the Valve F2P TF2 FAQ.(3 Letters ftw! <- ANOTHER ONE): http://www.teamfortress.com/freetoplay/faq.php