# Do my brothers have to download or have another 10GB worth of files to play TF2 on their account?

Tags: team-fortress-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [2nd Steam Account on the same Computer?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/55187/2nd-steam-account-on-the-same-computer)

They use the same computer that I do, but they use different Steam and computer accounts. I have already downloaded and installed the game on my account and my brothers want to play it on theirs. Do they have to redownload or reinstall the game? It is already installed on the computer. If there is a way for them to play the game without needing another 20GB, please EXPLAIN it because I searched a lot and no one specified different COMPUTER acounts, only different Steam accounts on the same computer account, which is not my case. 
I'm using Mac OSX 10.6.8.

Comment: See also: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/55187/2nd-steam-account-on-the-same-computer?rq=1

Comment: The linked question doesn't explicitly say what you're asking for, but it's the same deal.  You only need to download the game files once, and only have them stored in one place on your computer.  The worst case scenario is that you have to use symbolic links, <strike>but I don't think that's the case</strike> as can bee seen [here](http://www.fluther.com/93745/how-can-multiple-mac-os-x-users-play-tf2-without-installing/).

Comment: For a single steam installation the game files are common to all steam users.

Answer (score 3):

no, if you already have the game, all they have to do is to associate the game to their accounts, it's the same process to download, but the game will already be downloaded, so, it won't be necessary to download another 10+gb of files.